# how to make ssh return immediately

Tags: ssh

I just want to use ssh to verify port 22 is opening, and want to have the command return immediately. However, it's always prompting type password, do you have any ways to make the command return at once?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify the port is opened, then you can use `nmap`:

```
nmap -p 22 192.168.0.128
```

Where `192.168.0.128` is the IP of the host.